# Spring Security Error 5: MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Can people help me, I'm taking Professor Nelio Alves' spring course on Udemy and when starting the project it shows the error below: spring boot 2 and spring security 5

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4133) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar:2.9.4]
    at com.nelioalves.cursomc.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

classes:

```
package com.nelioalves.cursomc.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.nelioalves.cursomc.dto.CredenciaisDTO;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JWTUtil jwtUtil) {
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            CredenciaisDTO creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), CredenciaisDTO.class);
    
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(), creds.getSenha(), new ArrayList<>());
            
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
            return auth;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
        String username = ((UserSS) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(username);
        res.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        res.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");
    }
    
    private class JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
         
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(401);
            response.setContentType("application/json"); 
            response.getWriter().append(json());
        }
        
        private String json() {
            long date = new Date().getTime();
            return "{\"timestamp\": " + date + ", "
                + "\"status\": 401, "
                + "\"error\": \"Não autorizado\", "
                + "\"message\": \"Email ou senha inválidos\", "
                + "\"path\": \"/login\"}";
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.nelioalves.cursomc.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.nelioalves.cursomc.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter;
import com.nelioalves.cursomc.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import com.nelioalves.cursomc.security.JWTUtil;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/h2-console/**"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET = {
            "/produtos/**",
            "/categorias/**",
            "/estados/**"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST = {
            "/clientes/**",
            "/auth/forgot/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
        
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil));
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil, userDetailsService));
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I tried but it doesn't work. What I do is define a static inner class LoginAttempt and use ObjectMapper to read the JSON as an instance of it.

```
package com.nelioalves.cursomc.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.nelioalves.cursomc.dto.CredenciaisDTO;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JWTUtil jwtUtil) {
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }
    
    
    static class CredenciaisDTO {
        private String email;
        private String senha;
        public CredenciaisDTO() {}
        public String getEmail() { return email; }
        public String getSenha() { return senha; }
        public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
        public void setSenha(String senha) { this.senha = senha; }
    }

    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
        //  CredenciaisDTO creds = new ObjectMapper()
         //           .readValue(req.getInputStream(), CredenciaisDTO.class);
    
            CredenciaisDTO creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), CredenciaisDTO.class);
             
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(), creds.getSenha(), new ArrayList<>());
            
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
            return auth;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
        String username = ((UserSS) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(username);
        res.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        res.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");
    }
    
    private class JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
         
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(401);
            response.setContentType("application/json"); 
            response.getWriter().append(json());
        }
        
        private String json() {
            long date = new Date().getTime();
            return "{\"timestamp\": " + date + ", "
                + "\"status\": 401, "
                + "\"error\": \"Não autorizado\", "
                + "\"message\": \"Email ou senha inválidos\", "
                + "\"path\": \"/login\"}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all of this code is outdated, handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, there has been an active choice to not include this type of code in spring security because of the security issues. JWTs should not be used as sessions, i suggest you find a different course if that is what you are looking for or just read the official docs.